# Tomcat - Axis 1.4 : (411)Length Required

Tags: java, http, tomcat, axis

**AxisFault  faultDetail :**
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Please refer attached screen snap.[image]

**Solution tried :**    `_call.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HEADER_TRANSFER_ENCODING_CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);`

**It didn't worked.** Kindly advise some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied below code and it works

```
Hashtable httpHeaders = new Hashtable();
httpHeaders.put(HTTPConstants.HEADER_TRANSFER_ENCODING_CHUNKED, false);
_call.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Hashtable chunkedTable = new Hashtable();
chunkedTable.put(HTTPConstants.HEADER_TRANSFER_ENCODING,HTTPConstants.HEADER_TRANSFER_ENCODING_CHUNKED);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.